# How to simplify many conditions for multi listview item selection?

Tags: android, listview

I have two Listviews and many items in my listviews;

List1

```
private String[] list1 = {"A", "B", "C", "CD", "D", "E", "EF", "F", "FG", "G", "H", "JS", "J", "K", "M", "N", "P",
            "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Y", "Z", "ZA", "ZB", "ZC"};
```

List2

```
 private String[] list2 = {"01", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"};
```

and my listview adapters are (i have multi list views in my activity);

```
final ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
final ListView listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);

listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_elements_im, list1));
listView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_elements_im, list2));
```

for "A" and "01" item selections i wrote this code ;

All codes are here ;

```
package com.onuroid.onur.Asistanim;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
 * Created by Tasardor on 12/21/2016.
 */

public class Tolerans extends Activity {

    public static double D;
    public static double TS_Gecici1;
    public static double TS_Gecici2;
    public static double TS1;
    public static double TS5;
    public static double TS7;
    private DecimalFormat precision;
    private String[] list1 = {"A", "B", "C", "CD", "D", "E", "EF", "F", "FG", "G", "H", "JS", "J", "K", "M", "N", "P",
            "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Y", "Z", "ZA", "ZB", "ZC"};
    private String[] list2 = {"01", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"};
    private String[] list3 = {"a", "b", "c", "cd", "d", "e", "ef", "f", "fg", "g", "h", "js", "j", "k", "m", "n", "p",
            "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "x", "y", "z", "za", "zb", "zc"};
    private String[] list4 = {"01", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_isotoleranslar);
        final ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        final ListView listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        ListView listView3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list3);
        ListView listView4 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list4);
        listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_elements_im, list1));
        listView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_elements_im, list2));
        listView3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_elements_am, list3));
        listView4.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_elements_am, list4));
        final EditText temelolcu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.temel_olcu);
        final TextView TT1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol1);
        final TextView TT2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol2);
        final TextView TT3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol3);
        final TextView TT4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol4);
        final TextView TT5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol5);
        final TextView TT6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol6);
        final TextView TT7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol7);
        final TextView TT8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol8);
        final TextView TT9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol9);
        final TextView TT10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol10);
        final TextView TT11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tol11);
        precision = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

        temelolcu.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {

/* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////A SEÇİLMİŞSE//////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
               if (listView1.isItemChecked(0)) {

                   if (temelolcu.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                   D = Double.valueOf(temelolcu.getText().toString());
                       if (D > 0 && D <=6 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.2700);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           TS5 = (D+TS1);
                           double TS3 = (0.27);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));
                           TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                       if (D > 6 && D <=10 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.2800);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.28);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 10 && D <=18 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.2900);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.29);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 18 && D <=30 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.3000);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.30);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 30 && D <=40 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.3100);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.31);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 40 && D <=50 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.3200);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.32);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 50 && D <=65 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.3400);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.34);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 65 && D <=80 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.3600);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.36);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 80 && D <=100 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.3800);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.38);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 100 && D <=120 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.4100);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.41);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 120 && D <=140 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.4600);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.46);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 140 && D <=160 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.5200);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.52);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 160 && D <=180 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.5800);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.58);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 180 && D <=200 ){
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.6600);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.46);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 200 && D <=225 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.7400);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.74);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 225 && D <=250 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (0.8200);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.82);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 250 && D <=280 ) {TS_Gecici1 = (0.9200);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (0.92);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 280 && D <=315 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (1.0500);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (1.05);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 315 && D <=355 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (1.2000);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (1.20);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 355 && D <=400 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (1.3500);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           TS5 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (1.35);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 400 && D <=450 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (1.5000);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (1.50);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                       if (D > 450 && D <=500 ) {
                           TS_Gecici1 = (1.6500);
                           TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                           double TS3 = (1.65);
                           TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                           TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                   }}
/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////01 SEÇİLMİŞSE//////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
                if (listView2.isItemChecked(0)) {
                    if (temelolcu.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                        D = Double.valueOf(temelolcu.getText().toString());}
                    if (D > 0 && D <=3 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0003);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 3 && D <=10 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0004);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 10 && D <=18 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0005);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 18 && D <=50 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0006);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 50 && D <=80 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0008);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 80 && D <=120 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0010);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 120 && D <=180 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0012);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 180 && D <=250 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0020);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 250 && D <=315 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0025);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 315 && D <=400 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0030);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                    if (D > 400 && D <=500 ) {
                        TS_Gecici2 = (0.0040);
                        TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                        TS5 = (D+TS1);
                        TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                        TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}}}});


        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                           long arg3) {
            final String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            switch(value){
/* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// A  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
                case "A":
                        if (temelolcu.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                            D = Double.valueOf(temelolcu.getText().toString());
                            if (D > 0 && D <=6 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.2700);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                TS5 = (D+TS1);
                                double TS3 = (0.27);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));
                                TT5.setText(precision.format(TS5));}
                            if (D > 6 && D <=10 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.2800);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.28);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 10 && D <=18 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.2900);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.29);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 18 && D <=30 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.3000);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.30);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 30 && D <=40 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.3100);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.31);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 40 && D <=50 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.3200);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.32);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 50 && D <=65 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.3400);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.34);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 65 && D <=80 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.3600);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.36);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 80 && D <=100 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.3800);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.38);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 100 && D <=120 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.4100);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.41);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 120 && D <=140 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.4600);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.46);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 140 && D <=160 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.5200);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.52);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 160 && D <=180 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.5800);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.58);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 180 && D <=200 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.6600);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.46);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 200 && D <=225 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.7400);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.74);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 225 && D <=250 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.8200);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.82);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 250 && D <=280 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (0.9200);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (0.92);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 280 && D <=315 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (1.0500);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (1.05);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 315 && D <=355 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (1.2000);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (1.20);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 355 && D <=400 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (1.3500);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                TS5 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (1.35);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 400 && D <=450 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (1.5000);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (1.50);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                            if (D > 450 && D <=500 ) {
                                TS_Gecici1 = (1.6500);
                                TS1 = (TS_Gecici1 + TS_Gecici2);
                                double TS3 = (1.65);
                                TT1.setText(precision.format(TS1));
                                TT3.setText(precision.format(TS3));}
                        }break;}}});



    }

}
```

So my question is how to simplify this code ? Because it may be very long if i wrote this code for other item selections. All items have diffirent double values for "TS" doubles.

Table for double values

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You should consider making a class containing to store objects and their values  that you need and use a list of those objects to populate the listview

Comment: If you can't find a pattern to use to generate them programmatically, you're probably stuck with just adding them like you're doing.  You could move them out of the java into resources using a `string-array`.  Also, in your example, `list4` is the same as `list2`.  You can just assign `list2` to `listView4`.  It also looks like you can put `list1` through `.toLowerCase()` to get `list3`

Comment: Thanks for .toLowerCase()  and list4=list2 reminding. i will use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the arrays to resources, you can do it like this...

In strings.xml

```
<string-array name="list1">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
    <item>CD</item>
</string-array>
```

Then in `onCreate()`...

```
    String[] list1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list1);
```